JPA Criteria API - Issue after upgrading to Spring Boot 3
Recently we migrated our project to SpringBoot 3.2.1 and Hibernate 6.4.1.Final. Facing issues during Join using Criteria API.
Our entity classes:
@Entity
public class Pet {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer id;

 @Column(name="pname")
 private String name;

 @Column(name="pcolor")
 private String color;
}

@Entity
public class Owner {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer id;

 @Column(name="oname")
 private String name;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="pet_id")
 private Pet pet;
}

Joining using following method(works fine in SpringBoot <3):
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
Join<Pet, Owner> owner = pet.join("pet_id");

Getting following exception when running the code :
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type '**.owner' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Integer'
Tried downgrading hibernate to 6.2 version but facing same issue.Can anyone please help me with the exception.
